# how can i get remote user name from request in web api2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a requirement to identify remote user name and his domain in my webApi 2.0 but unable to do so.
I have tried to use few things

ViewBag.userName1 = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

```
ViewBag.userName2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();

 // will return the host name making the request
 ViewBag.remoteHost = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"];

// will return the computer name
 ViewBag.logonUser = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]; 
 ViewBag.remoteUser = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"];

 // will return the computer name
 ViewBag.serverName = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];

 System.Net.IPAddress[] strClientIPAddress = 
 System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(Environment.MachineName);
            ViewBag.strClientMachineName = 
 Environment.MachineName.ToString().Trim();
            ViewBag.strClientUserName = Environment.UserName.ToString().Trim();
            ViewBag.trClientDomainName = 
 Environment.UserDomainName.ToString().Trim();
            ViewBag.strClientOSVersion = 
 Environment.OSVersion.ToString().Trim();
```

and output is

```
NT AUTHORITY\IUSR 
null
10.91.145.111 
null
null
10.91.145.88 
53323-TZD-SITA 
IUSR 
NT AUTHORITY 
Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
```

can anyone please help me to get remote username and domain name?

Comment: I have resolved my issue after enabled window authentication in IIS.

Comment: That should probably be an answer not a comment.

Comment: Generally, unless you're enabling Impersonation, `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` will return the ApplicationPool identity

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue after enabled window authentication in IIS.